# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/jstl/core/IterationStatus

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl

I'm using ui:repeat in my facelet to iterate over a collection as following:

```
<ui:repeat var="name" value="#{loginBean.names}">  
                <h:outputLabel value="#{name}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

But it gives following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/eSchool] threw exception [com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/jstl/core/IterationStatus] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/faces/facelets/tag/jstl/core/IterationStatus
```

Advance thanks for help.

Comment: It seems you have multiple versions of jstl jars in classpath.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be running a barebones JSP/Servlet container like Tomcat and not a fullworthy Java EE container like Glassfish. A JSP/Servlet container does not ship with [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) while Facelets needs it for the `<ui:repeat>`, `<c:xxx>` and `<fn:xxx>` tags/functions.

Download [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar), drop it in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib` and rinse and this problem should disappear.